# Clean Com components when host the asp.net website in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, iis

I have a website hosted in IIS.
My application is all about writing and reading data to/from Excel document.

When I run the application from VS,i'm seeing only one EXCEL.exe all the time
But When I host the same application in IIS ,for every writing its creating one excel object and showing in Task-manager,Hence sometimes my website stops responding.

Below is my code

```
    try
            {
                xlApp = new app.Application();
                xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks;          
                xlWorkBook = xlWorkBooks.Open(FilePath, missing, false, missing, missing, missing, true, missing, missing, true, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);   
                xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(index);
//code …………………………….
                xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
                xlWorkBook.Save();
                boolWriteSuccess = true;
                xlApp.DisplayAlerts = true;
            }
Catch()
{
}            
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheets);
                xlWorkBook.Close(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
                xlWorkBooks.Close();
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkBooks);
                if (xlApp != null)
                    xlApp.Quit();
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlApp);
            }
```

Here is the screen shot of Task Manager when website hosted in IIS
[image]

I want to clean the excel.exe from task manager always but some how I'm unable to clean.
Please help me in this regard.

Comment: It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: Yep,I moved to open XML,thanks for ur suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

after saving the excel you should close the workbook. as each time you are creating nea app.application it will create new excel.exe
after saving excel use below code

```
    try {
foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("Excel"))
        {
            proc.Kill();
        }}catch(Exception ex){
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);}
```

Comment: First of all `ex.Message` isn't enough information for troubleshooting. Use `ex.ToString()`. More importantly, what is your code going to do after displaying the message? -1 for ignoring the exception.

Comment: ok sir. i just try to help to close the excel objects. and he already place the try catch block so i thought he didnt need to use my try catch. sorry, i will take care next time

Comment: Thanks for answer,but it will not work when multiple users are trying perform write/read operation on excel as excel processes will be killed.

Comment: yup then after saving excel close workbook. and destroy the object.or else you can identify your excel process and just kill the process you started

Comment: and this exception message we show to customer.. it is good habbit to show only ex.message and log the ex.tostring() in audit file.